# Java escaping escape sequence

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I want to escape escape sequences in a string.

Example: if I had a string whose contents were "\n\u0073", I need to escape them in such a way that if I printed it to the command line, I would see

```
this:
\n\u0073
instead of:

s
```

I'll also be escaping double quotes (") and backslashes (\), and I figured out an expression to escape those already:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\"\\\\])");
String str = p.matcher("\"\n\u0073\\"").replaceAll("\\\\$1");
```

This yields me:

```
\"
s\\
```

It doesn't take care of the escape sequences, though. What I want is:

```
\"\n\u0073\\
```

What modifications do I need to make to escape the escape sequences?

Comment: If you have the string literal `"\n\u0073"` in your code, it's too late, because at runtime **there is no escape sequence.** At runtime, that string is a newline character followed by a lowercase `s`.

Comment: You need to manually map them. Java does not know that you want an `"\n"` when it sees a `'\u0010'` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html). There is method `escapeJava()` on it. Unfortunately, imo, there is no way to escape unicode literals like *\u0073* so for your example input *"\"\n\u0073\""*, `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\"\n\u0073\"")` will return `\"\ns\"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("= First try =");
        System.out.println("\n\u0073");
        System.out.println("= Second try =");
        System.out.println("\n\\u0073");
    }

}
```

Which will output this:

```
= First try =

s
= Second try =

\u0073
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  It works 100%... the only weak point is that I have an explicit case for each character needed.  I'm not sure if there's a way around that, although perhaps you could get around that by making a case for an entire *range* of characters.  I don't think RegEx can match a character definition like `\u0073`, but I don't know for sure.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String unescaped = "\n\u0073";
    System.out.println("Version 1:\n" + unescaped);
    System.out.println("\nVersion 2:");
    printEscaped(unescaped);
}

public static void printEscaped(String unescaped) {
    for (char c : unescaped.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case ('\n'):
                System.out.print("\\n");
                break;
            case ('\u0073'):
                System.out.print("\\u0073");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Version 1:

s

Version 2:
\n\u0073
```

Another potential problem for wider use is that it works on characters even if they **weren't** defined by escape sequence.  For example, `printEscaped("s")` will print the same thing as `printEscaped("\u0073")`: they will both print `\u0073`.  So you have to be careful to **only** call the method on strings where you are sure you want every character printed in "escape notation."